# Convert multiple files with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, conversion, file-conversion

I'm trying to setup AutoHotkey to automatically convert a selected file to PNGs when pressing a CTRL+ENTER. To do the conversion, I'm using the [CLI version of Filestar](https://filestar.com/command-line-tools).

I have figured it out how to get this to work with one file:

```
^Enter::
    Backup := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = 
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait, 1
    Type := FileExist(Clipboard)
    If Type = A
    {
        Command := "C:\Program Files (x86)\Filestar\filestarcli.exe -i """ . Clipboard . """ -c ""convert to png"""
        Run, %Command%,,Min
    }
    Clipboard := Backup
return
```

Is it possible to make this work for multiple files?

Comment: Look at splitting up the `clipboard` variable by line (`\r\n`). Each line will contain the full path and filename of the file you want to process. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Comment: Great. I can probably figure it out with that hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use `` Loop, Parse, CLIPBOARD, `n, `r `` which loops every CLIPBOARD line (`%A_LoopField%`) using the delimiter `` `n `` for new line and omits the carriage return character `` `r ``

```
If Type = A
{    
    Loop, Parse, CLIPBOARD, `n, `r
    {
        Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Filestar\filestarcli.exe -i "%A_LoopField%" -c "convert to png", , Hide
    }
}
```